# Python Unicode in files

Tags: python, unicode

I can't get a grip on how Python handles Unicode in files...

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write('abc')
f.close()
```

That gives a file of 3 bytes.

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write('abcé')
f.close()
```

That gives a file of 5 bytes (the é takes up two bytes but how does Python knows that it must read 2 bytes there?)

```
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write('abcそ')  # a Japanese character
f.close()
```

That gives a file of 6 bytes (the そ takes up three bytes but how does Python knows that it must read 3 bytes there?)

So I can understand that Unicode takes two bytes, but it is sometimes 1, or 2 or 3 bytes, I fail to see how it works.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_code, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8

Comment: I don't know why this matters but that's not a Chinese character.

Comment: oops ... you're right it's Japanese, changed the comment...

Comment: Besides the Wikipedia links, there is also [this article by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: @John, thanx I have that book on the shelf ;-) just wasn't aware that the .write defaults to utf-8... however I should have known...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, it writes the output file with an encoding of [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), which is a variable-length encoding: it encodes ASCII characters (code points U+0000-U+007F) using 1 byte, code points U+0080-U+07FF (which includes Latin-1 characters such as é) using 2 bytes, code points U+0800-U+FFFF (which includes Chinese and Japanese characters such as そ) using 3 bytes, and code points U+10000-U+10FFFF using 4 bytes.

If you want to use a different encoding, such as UTF-16, you can use [`str.encode`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.encode) to use your desired encoding:

```
# Save the string as UTF-16 little-endian
f = open('test.txt', 'w')
f.write(u'abcそ'.encode('utf-16le')  # Output will be 8 bytes
f.close()
```

Comment: thanks, the documentation http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html says nothing that the write defaults to utf-8, but this explains it all.

Comment: It's not so much what `write` does but rather how the interpreter interprets your code: your code is likely being saved to disk by your editor in UTF-8, so when the interpreter reads it, it sees a UTF-8 string literal, so that's what gets passed through to the file.

Comment: It was the python interpreter I used, so that defaults to UTF-8, thanx again!